# Double Vertical Scroll only on WooCommerce Pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Our website has developed a double scroll bar caused by a bad overflow-y setting in the CSS however I'm struggling to find it on our website smkd.com. Can anybody assist?

As it stands i've currently gone through the theme's CSS file and cant seem to find it.

Comment: You may want to remove the commented code: https://nimb.ws/Coynck Line 7853

Comment: Remove this css rule from flatsome.css `html, body { overflow-x: hidden; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your file, [`flatsome.css`](https://smkd.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/css/flatsome.css?ver=3.12.1), you have the following rule:

```
html, body {
  overflow-x:hidden
}
```

Removing it seems to fix your issue.

Comment: But still the real problem is elsewhere. The footer is extended out because of absolute positioning of an element.

Comment: @m4n0 I narrowed it down to something to do with the header menu items that have drop downs. Removing those items seems to fix the double scrollbar as well as the extended footer. Removing the rule `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` also seems to fix it though it of course changes the layout a bit.